Apply Summarize over Summarize Columns in DAX
I have a dataset as below:

I have used SUMMARIZECOLUMNS to summarize by   Name and Year and calculated MAX(Points)  to get the below output:

VAR DistinctValueTable =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('MyTable'[Name], 'MyTable'[Year], "Max Points", MAX('MyTable'[Points]) )

I now need to SUM Max Points for each Name. How do I do this ?
SUMMARIZE(DistinctValueTable , [Name], SUM[Max Points])

is not working. I need my output to look like this


If you use a tablix or matrix, you can skip the last step.
If you put Name on ROWS and then your [MaxPoints] measure on VALUES, you'll get what you're looking for:
Name Sum Of MaxPoints
A           4.50
B           3.00
Total       7.50
then you just format the visual and turn off Row Subtotals to get this:
Name Sum Of MaxPoints
A           4.50
B           3.00
